# cs50 week3 algorithm tideman sorting pairs problem

Tags: c, cs50, bubble-sort

Even though I can even compile my code, the result is a fault. I logically asked myself again and again if what is wrong, but I can't find the wrongs. It is the `sort_pairs()` function. I'm trying to use *`bubble sort.`* 
Here's my code:

```
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    int swap_counter = 0;
    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pair_count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (preferences[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] < preferences[pairs[i+1].winner][pairs[i+1].loser])
            {
                pairs[i].winner = pairs[i+1].winner;
                pairs[i].loser = pairs[i+1].loser;
                swap_counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    while (swap_counter != 0);
    return;
}
```

I checked other functions so far, and they are all correct except `sort_pairs()`.

Comment: This does not look like a bubble sort at all. The code in the block does not perform swapping.

Comment: It also doesn't descend the top-end of the iteration after each sweep, leaving the most-recent "bubbled" value where it landed and continuing with the next pass for the next-"greatest" pair to be placed. I suspect you should have considered that first *before* muddying the waters with a swap-detection algorithm that doesn't even work.

Comment: You've left out some relevant portions of your code, but assuming there are `pair_count` elements in `pairs`, you're indexing beyond the end of the array:  When `i` is `pair_count - 1`, `i+1` will be `pair_count`, which will index past the end of `pairs`.

Comment: Add `printf("Swapping index %i with index %i\n");` just inside the `if` block and the problem ought to be clear.

Comment: well, the answer to this question is in CS50's week4 lecture - memory. haha